# Moto G (1st Gen) xt1033 lollipop

Tags: downloading, ota-update, motorola-moto-g, 5.0-lollipop

Recently the 2014 edition of the Moto G got the Lollipop update. I wanted to know the exact date on which the 1st Gen Moto G will be getting the update?
Also, can flashing the update of the 2nd Gen on the 1st gen prove to be dangerous? Can anyone provide me with a link containing android lollipop for moto G to download?

Answer (score 1):

Flashing 2nd gen file into 1st gen phone can completely brick your phone!

Comment: Agreed with this; the company's decision to give two different phones the same name doesn't change the fact that they are different.